# Go compiler: error line number is incorrect giving 1048575 i.e. 0xFFFFF when problem is further on in the file

Tags: go, compiler-errors

I am testing code-generation functionality and deliberately creating very large .go source files.

However I see errors with go compiler at line `1048575` (which is `0xFFFFF`) such as:

```
generated.go:1048575:75: invalid character U+0040 '@'
generated.go:1048575:76: const declaration cannot have type without expression
generated.go:1048575:88: syntax error: unexpected E_Blah_Blah, expecting semicolon or newline or )
```

Is this a known limitation?

EDIT-1: Commenters asked for more info on content of generated file; further tests show when I deliberately introduce a new error at line 1048573 or 1048574 it gets reported as I'd expect, but if I introduced one at `1048575` or higher line number the file I always get the error reported at 1048575.

EDIT-2: I realise now the original issue `invalid character U+0040 '@'` was indeed a bug in my generated file but it was further down that line number the compiler tells me.

EDIT-3: **So I guess the question should really have been:
 is there a way to have the go-compiler give the correct line number for a problem if error further down than line 0xFFFFF?**

Comment: FWIW, I can't find any relevant-looking reference to those numbers (or those numbers + 1) in the Go compiler source code. But it could be me.

Comment: Can you show the code on that line? And possibly surrounding lines if they are relevant?

Comment: I can create a `.go` source file with more lines than that, and it compiles and runs fine. What's your `go version`?

Comment: If this is an issue with the current tooling implementation, it seems it would be more useful to submit a working reproduction on the Go issue tracker than here.

Comment: Without seeing what you have in your source file, we can safely assume you just have an invalid generated file. I have created a file 100 times bigger than yours, and it's fine.

Comment: Your errors and the posted code doesn't seem to match. The errors talk about the `@` char and constant declaration. Your quoted lines are a type definition.

Comment: @icza You are right - my generated file had a bug BUT it was at a very high line number,  higher than 1048575 that the compiler was telling me !

Comment: @k1eran what is the "very high line number"?

Comment: @mkopriva 1048576 or beyond

Comment: @k1eran your first edit states that the bad-line-number happens whenever there is an error on line `1048576` or above, however this observation was made before edit-2, so I'm just wondering, if you introduce another bug, at 1048576 or above, *after* you've removed the `@` bug, do you still get the bad-line-number issue? The max value for the line number that can be displayed reliably seems to be `1073741824` (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/syntax/pos.go#L11)

Comment: @mkopriva yes. when I fix all my errors and create a new one I get a err at 1048575

Comment: Filed an issue here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was:

- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36850
  i.e. *Compiler bug: error line number is capped at 0xFFFFF*

as per comment from  @icza

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a known limitation ?

No.